# instance latency in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, latency

I am running a free application and using 1 max idle instance using GAE's Python runtime.

According to http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html,

> Your application's latency has the biggest impact on the number of
>   instances needed to serve your traffic. If you service requests
>   quickly, a single instance can handle a lot of requests.

This seems to suggest that adjusting the slider in 'Application Settings' to minimum latency would be best.

However, according to http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings.html#Setting_the_Minimum_Pending_Latency,

it seems like having a high latency is good for preventing load spikes from spinning up new instances.

So is latency basically a tradeoff between ability to respond to request spikes (high latency) vs. number of requests handled over a given time period (low latency)?

Comment: By latency, the docs mean your code's latency to respond to requests. Adjusting the slider has nothing to do with that. If you experience high latency but your code is fast, it means AppEngine needed to start a new instance of your app. That might be because you just uploaded it, or nobody used it for a long time and the idle instance has been shut down, or an other running instance is stuck.

Answer (score 4):

"Pending latency" refers to how long a request can be sitting in the queue before App Engine decides to spin up another instance.  If all of your app instances are busy when a request arrives, the request will wait in a queue to be handled by the next available instance.  If it's there beyond the minimum, App Engine may decide to start up a new instance to handle the request.  (There's also a maximum pending latency setting you can adjust.)

The minimum pending latency is configurable because starting up a new instance takes time and costs money.  A larger minimum pending latency means App Engine will hold onto pending requests longer (and make them wait) before starting new instances, favoring instance cost to the ability to handle more traffic.  A smaller minimum pending latency means App Engine will start new instances more often, as traffic picks up.

The term "latency" simply refers to how long it takes for your app to respond to a request.  The faster your app can respond to requests, the more requests a single instance can handle, and the shorter the request queue will typically be.  Lower latency is always good, but it's up to the app to do what it needs to do quickly.

Comment: Hi Dan, though your answer is 4 years old, it's still relevant. What's the difference between `<min-pending-latency>` and `<max-pending-latency>`?

Comment: Both values refer to when the auto scaler decides to start a new instance when it notices unfulfilled requests in the pending queue. The minimum says "don't try to start a new instance until a request has been sitting for at least this long." The maximum says "if a request has been sitting for this long, start a new instance." Some wiggle room between the two values, or a value of "automatic" for the maximum (the default), gives the scaler permission to guess what resources will be needed when. Reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#min_pending_latency